# CSS Drop Down Menu disappearing

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

http://nqmedia.co.uk/

When i roll over personal, the option seems to disappear quite quickly.

I think its to do with the styling

Here is my code:

```
.topmenu {float: right; width: 710px; height: 45px; background-color: #3a5a93; margin-top: 50px; border-top-left-radius: 10px 15px;border-top-right-radius: 10px 15px; border-bottom-left-radius: 10px 15px; border-bottom-right-radius: 10px 15px;}
.topmenu ul li {padding-top: 10px; float: left; margin-left: 10px;}
.topmenu ul li a:link {padding: 10px 20px; font: 14px genevaregular; color: #fff; text-decoration: none;}
.topmenu ul li a:visited {padding: 10px 20px; font: 14px genevaregular; color: #fff; text-decoration: none;}
.topmenu ul li a:hover {padding: 10px 20px; font: 14px genevaregular; color: #fff; text-decoration: none;}
.topmenu ul li a:active {padding: 10px 20px; font: 14px genevaregular; color: #fff; text-decoration: none;}
.topmenu ul li.current-menu-item a {color: #fff; }
.topmenu ul ul li {background-color: #3a5a93; padding:10px;float: none;}
.topmenu ul ul li:hover {background-color: #637ead; }
.topmenu ul ul {display: none; position: absolute; margin-top: 12px;}
.topmenu ul li:hover > ul {display: block;}
.topmenu ul ul li a {padding: 10px;}
```

Comment: Its best to include the specific HTML that is causing the problem in your post as well as the CSS.  Even better, create a jsfiddle of the problem code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `position: absolute;` on `.topmenu ul ul` to `position: relative;` and it works as intended.

Comment: thanks for this, however now on hover it pushes the other options out very slightly?