# Drop Down Menu Flickers and then Disappears (React & CSS)

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs

To whom who can help,

I am facing an issue regarding my drop down menu when hovering over navbar bar tab 'work'. After hovering cursor over 'work', you will then notice a drop down menu appear below. Now once you start moving your cursor downwards to click on a drop down option (social media, photo, video) the menu then disappears.

*Stackoverflow questions such as these havent solved my issue yet, but may be helpful?:

- [Drop down menu disappears on hovering over first option (blogger)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37266368/drop-down-menu-disappears-on-hovering-over-first-option-blogger)
- [CSS Drop Down Menu disappearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097859/css-drop-down-menu-disappearing)*

**Something I noticed:** If I take out the onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave} from the li elemenet in Navbar2.jsx, it will then show the menu after hovering. After your naviagte mouse away from menu the menu stays up.

- I have added an **image** and my **code** code below, as well as my **repo**.
- Note: I was told in the FCC forum that my file paths were breaking. However the last I pushed, everything was up to date and working. All images are named correctly and should point to correct imports. Please let me know in detail if there is an issue, but it should work or please refer to code below.

Image: [image]

Repo: https://github.com/DeBoer753/m-photography-PROJECT

REACT (NavBar2)

```
// REACT:
import React, { useState } from 'react'

// ROUTER:
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

// COMPONENTS:
import DropDown from './DropDown'

// IMGS:
import cbmLogo from '../../imgs/CBMedia_Black.png'

// CSS:
import './NavBar2.css' 

// NAVBAR2:
export default function NavBar2() {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false)
  const [dropdown, setDropdown] = useState(false)

  const handleClick = () => setClick(!click)
  const closeMobileMenu = () => setClick(false)

  const onMouseEnter = () => {
    if (window.innerWidth < 960) {
      setDropdown(false)
    } else {
      setDropdown(true)
    }
  }

  const onMouseLeave = () => {
    if (window.innerWidth < 960) {
      setDropdown(false)
    } else { 
      setDropdown(false)
    }
  }

  return (
    <>

      <nav className='navbar'>
        
        <div className='logo-name-box'>
          <Link to='/'><img src={cbmLogo} className='cbm-logo' alt="" srcset=""/></Link>
          <Link to='/' className='navbar-logo'>Blossom Media</Link>
        </div>
        <div className='menu-icon' onClick={handleClick}>
          <i className={click ? 'fas fa-times' : 'fas fa-bars'} />
        </div>

        <ul className={click ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
          <li className='nav-item'><Link to='/services' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu }>Services</Link></li>
          <li className='nav-item' onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}><Link to='/work' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>Work <i className='fas fa-caret-down'/></Link></li>
          {dropdown && <DropDown />}
          <li className='nav-item'><Link to='/reviews' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu }>Reviews</Link></li>
          <li className='nav-item'><Link to='/about' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu }>About</Link></li>
          <li className='nav-item'><Link to='/contact' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu }>Contact</Link></li>
        </ul>

      </nav>

    </>
)
}
```

CSS (NavBar2)

```
.navbar {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 20px rgb(54, 54, 54);
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 6;
  font-family:'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.logo-name-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-left: 24px;
  gap: 10px;
}

.cbm-logo {
  width: 50px;
}

.navbar-logo {
  color: #000000;
  justify-self: start;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  font-weight:500;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  width: 280px;
  align-self: center;
}

.fa-firstdraft {
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.nav-menu {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, auto);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 70vw;
  justify-content: end;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

.nav-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 80px;
}

.nav-links {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}

.nav-links:hover {
  background-color: #1888ff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.fa-bars {
  color: #000000;
}

.nav-links-mobile {
  display: none;
}

.menu-icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {

  .navbar {
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .NavbarItems {
    position: relative;
  }

  .nav-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: -180%;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
  }

  .nav-menu.active {
    background: #242222;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-left: 0px;
    border: 1px red solid;
  }

  .nav-links {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2rem;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    border: 1px red solid;
  }

  .nav-links:hover {
    background-color: #1888ff;
    border-radius: 0;
  }

  .navbar-logo {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -75px;
    margin-left: 0;
    transform: translate(25%, 50%);
  }

  .menu-icon {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: translate(-100%, 60%);
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .fa-times {
    color: #040404;
    font-size: 2rem;
  }

  .nav-links-mobile {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    margin: 2rem auto;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 80%;
    background: #1888ff;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }

  .nav-links-mobile:hover {
    background: #fff;
    color: #1888ff;
    transition: 250ms;
  }

}
```

REACT (DropDown)

```
// REACT:
import React, { useState } from 'react'

// ROUTER:
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

// DATA:
import { MenuItems } from './MenuItems' // this deconstructs and finds the variable holding the data

// CSS:
import './DropDown.css' 

export default function DropDown() {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false)

  const handleClick = () => setClick(!click)
  return (
    <>
    <ul onClick={handleClick} className={click ? 'dropdown-menu clicked' : 'dropdown-menu'}>
      {MenuItems.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <li key={index}><Link className={item.cName} to={item.path} onClick={() => setClick(false)}>{item.title}</Link></li>
        )
      })}
    </ul>
    </>
  )
}
```

CSS (DropDown)

```
.dropdown-menu {
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  right: 260px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: start;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
  background: #474747;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-menu li:hover {
  background: rgba(242, 242, 242, 0.48);
}

.dropdown-menu.clicked {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-link {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suspicion of the `onMouseLeave` is correct - the problem is that you set `onMouseLeave` on the `li`, so whenever the mouse leaves that `li` it will trigger the handler to `setDropdown(false)`.

You'll want to render the `<DropDown />` *inside* of the `li`, so hovering over the dropdown will not trigger the `onMouseLeave` handler. Something like this:

```
<li onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}>
  <Link>...</Link>
  {dropdown && <DropDown />}
</li>
```